# Unable to share project from intellij on github

Tags: git, version-control, github, intellij-idea

I am trying to share my project from intellij Idea(12.1.4) to github.I have created an account and followed [these](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/using-github-integration.html) to create an account on github and saved the credentials in the IDE settings. Also when I test version Control -> Github, it shows connection successful. But when I go to VCS->Import into version control-> share project into github, it shows

```
Couldn't identify the version of Git- stopped by timeout.
```

Git is installed and configured properly as I am able to commit.But when I try to push, the error:

```
Can't push,because no remotes are defined
```

Shows up.I suspect that the errors are related. So how should I share the project on github and what is causing the error(s)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add remote to the `.git/config`, either manually or via the `git remote add ...` command.

It's [not possible to add remotes directly from the IDE](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-87099).

Comment: The post was 13 months old and for version 11.1.2 .Is it still not implemented?

Comment: Hmm! I have solved the issue as you said thru git terminal. Thanx!!

Comment: Looks like IntelliJ git support is still horrible.  Same issue exists to this day.  Appears to try to override the default (and push to nothing) through the GUI.  Setting remote in CLI doesn't appear to help the GUI.  Best just stick to doing git from the CLI...